# Javascript-esq random floating point number 0-1 in Racket?

Tags: random, floating-point, racket

I've checked out the docs for this on docs.racket-lang.org, and looked all over the internet for a possible implementation of this, but all I'm looking for is a random number generating function that generates a number between 0 and 1. For instance, in Javascript:

```
> Math.random()
0.16275149723514915
```

I'm looking for this in Racket, and I'd implement it if I could, but I just don't have the chops (yet).

Comment: Have you seen [the docs on random numbers](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28part._.Random_.Numbers%29)?

Comment: Yes I was looking at those. But I've figured a way around the problem, so I think I'm fine. Is there a way to delete questions?

Comment: @ChristopherDumas Don't delete questions (within 30 days of posting); [doing that may damage your ability to ask questions in future](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/13). Instead, just let someone answer the question (or answer it yourself), and you can accept the answer if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just use `(random)`. Example usages:

```
> (random)
0.9007041222291202
> (random)
0.6808167485543256
```